# Combine data in multiple worksheets into one array

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched for such a topic and found a UDF that combines 2d arrays into one array. I tried to loop through the worksheets like that and store the data in alll worksheets except "Search" worksheet

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a, temp, ws As Worksheet, m As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> "Search" Then
                m = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                temp = ws.Range("A4:L" & m).Value
                On Error Resume Next
                'If UBound(a) > 0 Then GoTo nextP
                If a = Empty Then a = temp
                On Error GoTo 0
nextP:
                a = Combine(a, temp)
            End If
        Next ws
        
        Stop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'a = Range("A1:C2").Value
    'b = Range("A4:C5").Value
    'Range("F1").Resize(UBound(a, 1) * 2, UBound(a, 2)).Value = Combine(a, b)
    'Range("J1").Resize(UBound(a, 1), UBound(a, 2) * 2).Value = Combine(a, b, False)
End Sub

Function Combine(a, b, Optional f As Boolean = True)
    Dim c, lb As Long, m_A As Long, n_A As Long, m_B As Long, n_B As Long, m As Long, n As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    If TypeName(a) = "Range" Then a = a.Value
    If TypeName(b) = "Range" Then b = b.Value
    lb = LBound(a, 1)
    m_A = UBound(a, 1)
    n_A = UBound(a, 2)
    m_B = UBound(b, 1)
    n_B = UBound(b, 2)
    If f Then
        m = m_A + m_B + 1 - lb
        n = n_A
        If n_B <> n Then Combine = False: Exit Function
    Else
        m = m_A
        If m_B <> m Then Combine = False: Exit Function
        n = n_A + n_B + 1 - lb
    End If
    ReDim c(lb To m, lb To n)
    For i = lb To m
        For j = lb To n
            If f Then
                If i <= m_A Then
                    c(i, j) = a(i, j)
                Else
                    c(i, j) = b(lb + i - m_A - 1, j)
                End If
            Else
                If j <= n_A Then
                    c(i, j) = a(i, j)
                Else
                    c(i, j) = b(i, lb + j - n_A - 1)
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Combine = c
End Function
```

The code works and I got one array but the number of rows are duplicates .. Example: if the number of rows in all worksheets are 20 rows, I got an array of 40 rows ..
Any idea how to fix that?
Simply my request is about how to append 2d array to th main array??

Comment: Cycle through the sheets and create an array of arrays, keeping a running sum of the number of rows.  Then loop that array of arrays and load an output array the size based on the running total.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I am trying to achieve but I got stuck. I have put the code that I could do till now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array of arrays to collect the data then iterate that to fill the single array:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a, temp, ws As Worksheet, m As Long
    ReDim a(1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1)
    
    Dim x As Long
    x = 1
    
    Dim rowscnt As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> "Search" Then
                m = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                a(x) = ws.Range("A4:L" & m).Value
                rowscnt = rowscnt + UBound(a(x), 1)
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next ws
     x = 1
    ReDim temp(1 To rowscnt, 1 To 12)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To UBound(a(i), 1)
            Dim k As Long
            For k = 1 To 12
                temp(x, k) = a(i)(j, k)
            Next k
            x = x + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    
    'do something with temp
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much.

Comment: What if I have a 2d array and I need to append column to it. For example the array from each sheet. I need to add a column to the array with the sheet name. Will I have to loop or is there an easier approach?

Comment: I would create another simple 1 d array that keeps the sheet name in the same relative location.  Then add a column to Temp and in the loop that loads Temp just fill column 13 with the sheet name from the 1d array.

Comment: Will I add the 1d array inside that loop `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` ..?How can I add to temp array (I am not sure how to start solving that)?!

Comment: New questions get new posts.  It is a little too large to answer in a comment.

Comment: I have added a line `ReDim b(1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1)` then changed this line `ReDim temp(1 To rowscnt, 1 To 13)`, and used this line `temp(x, 13) = b(i)` after the loop of k but it seems incorrect steps which I did.

Comment: Please post what you tried in a new post and ask a new question.  It is too large for comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved it. Besides the lines I did I had to fill the 1d array with the sheet name so I used this line `b(x) = ws.Name`

Answer (score 1):

Try the next adapted code, please. It will return in "A1" of "Search" sheet:

```
Sub TestCombine()
    Dim a, temp, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, m As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.name <> "Search" Then
            m = ws.cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
            temp = ws.Range("A4:L" & m).value
            If Not IsArray(a) Then
                a = temp
            Else
                a = combineArr(a, temp)
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    wb.Sheets("Search").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(a), UBound(a, 2)).value = a
End Sub

Private Function combineArr(arr1, arr2)
    Dim arr3, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    If UBound(arr1) * UBound(arr1, 2) <= 65535 Then
        arr3 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr1) 
    Else
        arr3 = transP(arr1)
    End If
    ReDim Preserve arr3(1 To UBound(arr1, 2), 1 To UBound(arr1) + UBound(arr2))
    k = UBound(arr1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr2)
        k = k + 1
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr2, 2)
            arr3(j, k) = arr2(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    If UBound(arr3) * UBound(arr3, 2) <= 65535 Then
        combineArr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr3)
    Else
        combineArr = transP(arr3)
    End If
End Function
```

And the necessary custom transpose function:

```
Private Function transP(arr As Variant) As Variant 'instead of Applicaton.Transpose
    Dim trans As Variant, r As Long, C As Long
    ReDim trans(1 To UBound(arr, 2), 1 To UBound(arr))
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For C = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            trans(C, r) = arr(r, C)
        Next C
    Next r
    transP = trans
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tested it but got `subscript out of range` at this line `arr3(j, k) = arr1(i, j)`. The number of rows in each worksheet is different from each other.

Comment: @YasserKhalil Did you use the code as it is? It works for me on a test workbook. And, of course, the number of rows can be different. The iteration is done according to `Ubound(arr2)`.

Comment: I just changed the target cell to A100 instead of A1 and didn't change anything else.

Comment: I changed this line `arr3(j, k) = arr2(i, j)` and it works well now.

Comment: This is what I already did, too... I could see that it was a mistake.

Comment: Just a note for future users, Application.Transpose or WorksheetFunction.Transpose has a limit and if the data set gets too large it will fail.

Comment: @Scott Craner: Yes, indeed. It looks that the limitations means 65535 (2^16) elements, if I remember well. In such a case a custom function can be used. I built one using it for such cases. And the speed difference is not considerable. In fact, I will edit my code and make it working with the above mentioned function, too... But the version using a jagged array and **calculating the final array number of elements** during sheets iteration is better, I admit it.

Answer (score 1):

I have also found the following piece of code but I have not the source to be honest

```
Sub MyDemo()
    Dim arr, temp, ws As Worksheet, f As Boolean
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Search" Then
        temp = ws.Range("A4:L" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
        If f Then
            arr = ArrayJoin(arr, temp)
        Else
            arr = temp
            f = True
        End If
        End If
    Next ws
    Sheets("Search").Range("A100").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
End Sub

Function ArrayJoin(ByVal a, ByVal b)
    Dim i As Long, ii As Long, ub As Long
    ub = UBound(a, 1)
    a = Application.Transpose(a)
    ReDim Preserve a(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To ub + UBound(b, 1))
    a = Application.Transpose(a)
    For i = LBound(b, 1) To UBound(b, 1)
        For ii = 1 To UBound(b, 2)
            a(ub + i, ii) = b(i, ii)
        Next ii
    Next i
    ArrayJoin = a
End Function
```

Comment: One note to be aware.  Application.Transpose has a limit and if the data set gets too large it will fail.

Comment: What is the limit..? How many rows can be used when using transpose?

Comment: It is not the number of rows but the number of items as well as the size of those items.  it is around 64,000.